# Open source program for graphemic conversion from English to Korean

Tags: open-source, nlp

I am looking for an open source program that can perform [graphemic conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_scripts) from English to Korean.

E.g. if given as input "Francky" it should return something similar to "프랭키", which in Korean sounds similar to Francky. The meaning doesn't matter, the only goal is to keep the pronunciation as similar as possible.

Any code license is fine.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi) but open source?

Comment: @Timmy Yes, thanks, actually your link does seem to be open source: https://code.google.com/p/conv2kr/ :)

Comment: I should have read the page more thoroughly. I'll make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

I found this tool: [Hong's Hangul Conversion Tools](http://www.sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi). It converts text from English to Korean and vice versa through transliteration dictionaries. It is indeed open source as mentioned in the comments on the OP, and the [code](https://code.google.com/p/conv2kr/) is licensed under [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt).

Here is an example:

[image]